# Program NOT throwing S0C7 abend

Tags: cobol

I am newbie and doing some analysis with cobol. I have below code where I am expecting S0C7 abend. However, program is executing successfully. Please note that this is test program and I have provided Identification division although not shown in the snapshot. I am using enterprise cobol compiler 4.2

```
FILE SECTION.                                                   
*                                                                
FD  INFILE.                                                     
01 INFILE-REC                    PIC X(5).                      
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                                        
01 INFILE-STA        PIC X(2).                                  
01 NUMERIC-FIELD     PIC 9(3)V9(2) VALUE 0.                     
01 ALPHANUMERIC-FIELD     PIC X(5).                             
**************************************************               
PROCEDURE DIVISION.                                             
     OPEN INPUT INFILE                                           
     IF INFILE-STA = '00'                                        
        CONTINUE                                                 
     ELSE                                                        
        GO TO 000-MAIN-EXIT                                      
     END-IF                                                      
     READ INFILE                                                 
     IF INFILE-STA = '00'                                        
        CONTINUE                                                 
     ELSE                                                        
        GO TO 000-MAIN-EXIT                                      
     END-IF                                                      
     DISPLAY 'REC IS ------>' INFILE-REC                         
     MOVE INFILE-REC      TO NUMERIC-FIELD                       
                             ALPHANUMERIC-FIELD                  
     DISPLAY 'AFTER ADDING TO ALPHANUMERIC :' ALPHANUMERIC-FIELD 
     ADD 2 TO NUMERIC-FIELD.       
     DISPLAY 'AFTER ADDING TO NUMERIC :' NUMERIC-FIELD    
      .                                                   
000-MAIN-EXIT.                                           
     STOP RUN.
```

I am getting below output :-

```
REC IS ------>ABCDE                       
AFTER ADDING TO ALPHANUMERIC :ABCDE       
AFTER ADDING TO NUMERIC :34700
```

Please advice.

Comment: What do you expect should be causing this abend?

Comment: I am moving input which is alphabetic to numeric data type variable and trying to perform arithmetic operation. I thought it should give S0C7

Comment: First, your NUMERIC-FIELD has an implied decimal point, which isn't shown with the DISPLAY.  Taking 34700 and subtracting 2 gives 34500.  The 345 are what's left of the CDE string.  So what happened in your MOVE statement is the ABCDE didn't fit in the 9(3).  Only the CDE fit.  Your move chopped off the leading X'C' byte and left 34500.  Then you added 2 and got 34700 (implied decimal point).

Comment: Thanks for response! Yes, you are correct! But, I am just wondering why compiler is converting Alphabets into numbers? May I know which compiler option is responsible here? I am currently using  cobol enterprise 4.2.

Comment: The alphanumeric to numeric MOVE is not a compiler option.  It's the default behavior of the MOVE statement in the COBOL language.

Comment: What about [`NUMCHECK`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.4?topic=options-numcheck)?

Comment: @Vinayakkulkarni What is the output of `DISPLAY 'NUM-REC IS ' NUMERIC-FIELD` when done before the add?